# How to access a class inside a div using refs ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that I'm accessing using the ref in the div.

```
render() {
    return (
      <div ref="cellls" styleName="grid-wrap" onScroll={this.closeMenu.bind(this)}>
  <MyComponent/>
  )
}
```

when I access the `<MyComponent/>` using:

```
this.refs.cellls
```

results into a table with rows and columns like,

[image]

Now I want to check if a particular class- "wrapper-active" exists in this div.
How can I access this child element using refs?

Comment: this.refs.cellls.includes(' wrapper-active');

Comment: but this.refs.cellls is not a function, its a div element

Comment: you can define ref for component like this `<MyComponent ref="something" />` right?